# Return PLAYA field name?

Tags: playa

Is there any way to return the playa field's name (or an ID / short name / anything similar) within a playa loop? I basically need to pull two different playa fields, but treat them differently.

Readability-wise, I'd love to keep this as a single playa loop, but that isn't strictly necessary and might be my backup plan.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
{exp:playa:children field="missed|content" status="open" limit="10"}
  {if field == "missed"}
    display missed field one way
  {if:elseif field == "content"}
    display content field a different way
  {if:else}
    ...
  {/if}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

I'm hoping I'm just not seeing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check for the presence of a field or a status that's present in one type of entry, but not the other? For instance, if you're pulling from two separate channels, you could do something like this...

```
{if some_var_in_channel_1}
   ...
{if:elseif some_Var_in_channel_2}
  ...
{/if}
```

If it's channel based, could also use {channel_short_name} to compare against.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. The playa fields are set to pull in the exact same grouping of entries (same channel, cats, statuses, etc).

Comment: I'd suggest you just use a Playa loop for each field then as you suggest in your post.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem like the best answer right now. Thank you!